# How to set the email to field for pull request notification in GitHub?

Tags: email, github, pull-request

When someone comments on a pull request, I receive an email as shown below. How can I change the To: field to my team email address? Right now, "TF-ALM/Pivot.Core" is in names of "org/repo".

```
To: TF-ALM/Pivot.Core <noreply@invgithubprod1..com>
Cc: 
Subject: Re: [Pivot.Core] Feature cyber ark (#4)

Looks good!
—
Reply to this email directly or view it on GitHub Enterprise.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-notification-emails/

The To field in the email connects directly to the thread. That means that if you reply to the email, you'll actually be adding a new comment to the conversation.

Elijah Buck (GitHub Enterprise) 
Mar 29, 11:46 AM 
Hello,
It is not possible to change the To address. What problem are you trying to solve by changing the address?
Thanks,
Elijah